# How to optimize bitmap draw in Android?

Tags: android

In my Android app, I receive a remote video stream in a proprietary format. As a new network packet arrives, I decode it natively and obtain a bitmap. In the UI, this bitmap is displayed in an ImageView control via `setImageBitmap()` method.

I am able to process 12 to 14 frames per second. I am wondering if there is a way to optimize this in terms of performance. Perhaps I can use hardware acceleration, if possible.

Comment: you could use a custom View with custom drawing, this way there is no need to create temporary Bitmap again and again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a `VideoView` that already does all that kind of things for you?

However:

- I think you should use `SurfaceView` instead of `ImageView`. With `SurfaceView` you have your own dedicated thread that is just responsible for drawing on the canvas. Therefore redrawing is faster.
- I guess you are encoding a single Frame bitmap in an async thread which is completely fine. But you should think about how to parallelize that. Basically use a `ThreadPool` or something similar that decodes your video to single Bitmaps. Put them in a `Buffer` which can be a `Fifo`, `List` or `Queue` or whatever, but just keep in mind that one thread can be faster than another, so you better give every decoding task an order number so that you can add the encoded bitmap in correct order into the `Buffer`. The `SurfaceView` next should always take the first image from the buffer and display it on screen.
- Schedule the `SurfaceView` Thread redrawing to achive 60 frames per seconds. So not redraw over and over again in a `while-loop` think about a smarter (scheduled) solution.
- Only redraw if the `Buffer` contains enough images (you have to determine the number of images in the buffer by your own or google it). Otherwise display a "loading / buffering" animation
- Garbage Collection can take some time, so try to reduce the time garbage collection runs. Bitmap association can consume a lot of memory and therefore garbage collector needs to run often to find free memory for the next bitmap. So think about the video source file if you can deliver it with a width / height that is more suitable for smartphones (maybe different files for different display sizes). Think about how you can decrease memory consumption. There are various options in `BitmapFactory` that you can use to reduce memory consumption (which reduces running garbage collection) like `inSampleSize` or `inBitmap` which seems a good choice since all bitmaps should have the same width / height. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html). You could also reduce the Bitmap quality by using `BitmapConfig.RGB_565`.